# How to consolidate the response codes from jtl file

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I am using the JMeter for doing load testing. How can I consolidate the response codes from a generated JTL files?

Are there any best practices to generate the JTL file? (Like To get failed sampler request and response)

Answer (score 1):

If you open .jtl results file (by default it is normal [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) file) using [Microsoft Excel](https://office.live.com/start/Excel.aspx) or equivalent (like [LibreOffice Calc](https://www.libreoffice.org/discover/calc/)) you will be able to see `responseCode` column which will hold the [HTTP Status Codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) values for all [Samplers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers)

[image: JMeter Response Code]

The best practices of generating .jtl files is storing the absolute minimum data, and especially avoid of saving response data as it creates massive disk IO overhead and may ruin your test. However if you really need to store the response data - add the next lines to *user.properties* file:

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data.on_error=true
```

This will switch .jtl files output format to [XML](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/) and "tell" JMeter to save responses for failed requests. See [Configuring JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter) and [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) to learn how to precisely tune your JMeter instances using properties.

The general recommendations on JMeter usage you can find in the [JMeter Best Practices](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) guide

Comment: Thanks, Dmitri. How to save a request on failure.

Comment: I am getting the following error if open a file in excel "Can not load the specified XML or Schema source"